# java jar command in powershell script

Tags: java, powershell

I have been struggling with this problem since a couple days.

Here is a some java command i execute in powershell and from cmd shell it works perfectly:

```
java -jar some_program.jar "C:\Users\the_path_to_screenshot_folder\"
```

Now the problem is that I want to make a powershell script to put the command above into a loop but its not that easy. I have tried to put this command in variable but it doesnt work, also tried Start-Process embedded function, Start-Job but all these attempts failed. Do u have any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Tried:

- Start-Process powershell function
- Start-Job prowershell function
- put command into variable

Comment: Why in a loop ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `while ($true) { & java -jar some_program.jar "<path>" }` ?

Comment: Please show your attempt to use a loop and clarify in what way it didn't work.

Comment: [How to Use PowerShell For Loop, While Loop, and Other Loops](https://petri.com/how-to-use-powershell-for-while-loops/).

Comment: Read up on the Call Operator & inside this [Helpfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to generate the java commands inside a loop and write them to a script file for later execution.  Each java command will have been resolved into the kind of command that works under the powershell commandprompt.

Something similar is done in one of the demo examples for my template engine,  expand-csv.  The demo follows in a block.  Expand-csv is not relevant here, but you can view the repo of it in Github.com/Dcressey/Expand-Csv where this demo is one of two offered.

```
    Example 1:  CSV File
    --------------------
    
NAME,ID
John,18
Dave,19
Carmen,20
Eric,21
Tom,22
Lisa,23
Kyle,24
   
    Viewed as a table
    

NAME   ID
----   --
John   18
Dave   19
Carmen 20
Eric   21
Tom    22
Lisa   23
Kyle   24


    
    Example 1:  Template
    --------------------
    
& java -jar --create -user $name -id $id -file D:/HR/$name-$id-form.pdf
    
    Example 1:  Results
    -------------------
& java -jar --create -user John -id 18 -file D:/HR/John-18-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Dave -id 19 -file D:/HR/Dave-19-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Carmen -id 20 -file D:/HR/Carmen-20-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Eric -id 21 -file D:/HR/Eric-21-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Tom -id 22 -file D:/HR/Tom-22-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Lisa -id 23 -file D:/HR/Lisa-23-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Kyle -id 24 -file D:/HR/Kyle-24-form.pdf
```